# Error in giving inputs to the tensorflow serving model on sagemaker. {'error': "Missing 'inputs' or 'instances' key"}

Tags: json, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving, amazon-sagemaker

I have a custom model built-in TensorFlow. I am trying to deploy this model on amazon sagemaker for inference. The model takes three inputs and gives five outputs.
The name of the inputs are:

```
1.    input_image
2.    input_image_meta
3.    input_anchors
```

and the name of outputs are:

```
1    output_detections
2    output_mrcnn_class
3    output_mrcnn_bbox
4    output_mrcnn_mask
5    output_rois
```

I have successfully created the model endpoint on sagemaker and when I am trying to hit the request for the results, I am getting {'error': "Missing 'inputs' or 'instances' key"} in return.

The sagemaker endpoint gets created and the tensorflow server also starts(as shown in CloudWatch logs).
On the client side, I call the predictor using follwoing code:

```
request = {}
request["img_link"] = "image.jpg"
result = predictor.predict(request)
```

But when I print the result the following gets printed out, {'error': "Missing 'inputs' or 'instances' key"}
All the bucket connections for loading the image are in inference.py

Comment: What about the other inputs that your model expects?

Answer (score 2):

Tensorflow serving prediction api should have a key "instances" or "inputs" to modify your input. Your request body should be like this

```
{
    "instances": [{
        "input_image": DATA1,
        "input_image_meta": DATA2,
        "input_anchors": DATA3}]
}
```

More [information](https://tensorflow.google.cn/tfx/serving/api_rest)